# Giphy Search Using The Fetch Api

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm pretty new when it comes to working with Api's. I'm trying to query the URL string and return some Gifs.

```js
const gifForm = document.querySelector("#gif-form");
gifForm.addEventListener("submit", fetchGiphs);

function fetchGiphs(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const searchTerm = document.querySelector("#search").value;
  fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?&q=${searchTerm}&limit=100&api_key=3mIxmBZUIIPyb8R69gtxaW8Hsh74dFKV`)
  .then((response) => {return response.json(); })
  .then(data => showGiphs(data.images.fixed_width.url))
  .then(err => console.log(err));
}

function showGiphs(fixed_width) {
  const results = document.querySelector("#results");

  let output = '<div class="container">';
  fixed_width.forEach((url) => {
    console.log(url);
    
    output += `
  <img src="${data.images.original.fixed_width_url}"/>

`;
  });
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<form id="gif-form">
  <input type="text" id="search">
  <input type="submit" value="find">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

If I remove the `.then(data => showGiphs(data.images.fixed_width.url))` from the fetch and just `console.log` the data it's returning the search results that I want. However, when I try to map to the gif"data.images.fixed_width.url, I'm getting a console error of "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'fixed_width' of undefined"
    at `fetch.then.then.data`

Any help or push in the right direction would be awesome! Thank you! Also, if you'd like the view the demo you can view it here: https://codepen.io/Brushel/pen/jKgEXO?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple issues with your code.

The response from the API is an object, in this object there is `data` array, and each element in this array is information about each gif.

**Try:**

```js
const gifForm = document.querySelector("#gif-form");
gifForm.addEventListener("submit", fetchGiphs);

function fetchGiphs(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = document.querySelector(".search").value;
    fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?&q=${searchTerm}&limit=100&api_key=3mIxmBZUIIPyb8R69gtxaW8Hsh74dFKV`)
    .then((response) => {return response.json(); })
    .then((resp => {
        // Here we get the data array from the response object
        let dataArray = resp.data
        // We pass the array to showGiphs function
        showGiphs(dataArray);
    }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err)); // We use catch method for Error handling
}

function showGiphs(dataArray) {
  const results = document.querySelector(".results");
  let output = '<div class="container">';
  dataArray.forEach((imgData) => {
    output += `
  <img src="${imgData.images.fixed_width.url}"/>
`;
  });
  document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
    <form id="gif-form">
    <input type="text" class="search">
    <input type="submit" value="find">
</form>
<div class="results"></div>
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The response has a `data` property which is an array. If you want the first GIF in that array, that would look like this: `data.data[0].images.fixed_width.url`. So the full line would be `.then(data => showGiphs(data.data[0].images.fixed_width.url))`.

Comment: When I do that I get an error in my forEach loop saying 
"fixed_width.forEach is not a function"